# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `…eference chain: com.javainuse.model.User["role"])

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I'm trying to solve this error, I didn't find out a solution. I'm making a user management system with spring and angular. I read a lots tutorial and watched video, but now I can't understand how to solve that error.

this is my code:
Spring

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private String userName;
    private String userFirstName;
    private String userLastName;
    private String emailId;
    private String userPassword;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={PERSIST, DETACH})
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_ROLE",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
            },
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")
            }
    )
    private Set<Role> role;

} 

@Data
@Entity
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    private String roleName;
    private String roleDescription;
}

@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDao roleDao;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public User registerNewUser(User user) {
        Role role;
        Predicate<Role> roles = role1 -> role1.getRoleName().equals("Admin");
        if (user.getRole().stream().allMatch(roles)) {
             role = roleDao.findById("Admin").get();
        } else{
            role = roleDao.findById("User").get();
        }

        Set<Role> userRoles = new HashSet<>();
        userRoles.add(role);
        user.setRole(userRoles);
        user.setUserPassword(getEncodedPassword(user.getUserPassword()));

        return userDao.save(user);
    }


   


    public String getEncodedPassword(String password) {
        return passwordEncoder.encode(password);
    }
}


@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping({"/system/registerNewUser"})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('System')")
    public User registerNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
       return userService.registerNewUser(user);
    }
}
```

Angular code

```
import {Role} from "./Role";


export class User {

  userName!: string;
  userFirstName!: string;
  userLastName!: string;
  emailId!: string;
  userPassword!: string;
  role!: Role;
}

export interface Role {

    roleName: string;
    viewRoleName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedValue!: string;

  roles: Role[] = [
    {roleName: 'Admin', viewRoleName: 'Admin'},
    {roleName: 'User', viewRoleName: 'User'},
  ];

  user: User = new User();
  constructor(private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  saveUser(){
    this.userService.createUser(this.user).subscribe(data =>{
        console.log('createuser '+data);
        this.goToUsersList();
      },
      error => console.error(error));
  }

  goToUsersList(){
    this.router.navigate(['/system']);
  }


  create(){
    console.log(this.user);
    this.saveUser();
  }

}


<div class="container add-student-container">
  <div>
    <mat-card>
      <h3 style="text-align: center">Add New User Data</h3>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
          <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput  [(ngModel)] ="user.userFirstName" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
          <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)] ="user.userLastName"/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
          <mat-label>email</mat-label>
          <input matInput [(ngModel)] ="user.emailId"/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
          <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
          <input matInput  [(ngModel)] ="user.userName"/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input matInput  [(ngModel)] ="user.userPassword"/>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="form-element">
          <mat-label>Role</mat-label>
          <mat-select [(ngModel)] ="user.role" name="role">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let role of roles" [value]="role.roleName">
              {{role.viewRoleName}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="create()">Create</button>
      </div>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

 createUser(user: User): Observable<Object>{
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.userAuthService.getToken()});
    console.log('baseurl ' +this.baseURL+'/system/registerNewUser');
    console.log('header '+this.userAuthService.getToken());
    return this.httpclient.post<User>(`${this.baseURL}/system/registerNewUser`,user,{headers});
  }
```

The problem is the User class in Angular. I think that I'm wrong to define Role attribute.
Unfortunately I didn't find out a good solution for my error. Can anyone give me an hand to show me the solution or some tutorial that they show how to manage better what I wanna do.

Comment: is it that you are trying to add a user to the database but each time you are doing so, you get an error saying that the role can not be deserialized?

Comment: I think so, I have to find the right way to do that, but I didn't find out it. Please Do you have an idea or some example to show me?

Comment: Sadly , I do not have an example to show you but you can try changing the {{role.viewRoleName}} in your html to {{role.roleName}} and see if that works. Also, I will try to do it on my end since angular and spring boot is my main stack so I will keep you posted

Comment: I was not able to find a solution to this but I did find a video that  I think might be able to help, you can check it out and let me know if it works. https://youtu.be/8EWVMaXR2Os. The deserialization error usually occurs when parsing arrays . In this case, role_id and role_name